# How to copy value from next line below it

Tags: arrays, bash, perl, awk, sed

I am looking into Sed or Awk to figure this out, but I am complete lost. Don't have a starting point.
I have a file with a bunch of these, so I am thinking of using delimiter(,) and use index/array to copy a value and replace another index/array.

```
0001,324434344,Sterner,Erik B,B.A,1987
0002,324434344,Sterner,Erik B,M.A,2001,Columbia University
```

Since array[6] is empty in the first line. I want to copy the array[6] from the second line into the first one. I have a good idea of how to look through file and identify that array[6] is empty but, I just don't know how to copy the second line array[6] and replace the line before it. Any hints?
Result should be:

```
0001,324434344,Sterner,Erik B,B.A,1987,Columbia University
0002,324434344,Sterner,Erik B,M.A,2001,Columbia University
```

Comment: what is the field delimiter here? "Columbia university" appears to be after the 8th comma or so. Also, is it just about these two lines or something different? You probably will have to loop through the file twice in `awk`: once to store data, then to print it

Comment: the delimiter is the comma (,), and lookin at array[6] my mistake. let me fix.

Comment: what is the unique id here? the first field?

Comment: yea I noticed when I was replying , was making the edit lol. Thanks though.

Comment: Yes, the first field is unique (auto incremented)

Comment: Can you have multiple lines with empty fields that need to be populated from the first non-empty field you find or is it always just 1?

Comment: @EdMorton Yes, it is possible there can be two first lines that have empty fields. One small issue but I didn't want to make it too complicated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reverse the lines! Then it should be trivial to store the most current non-blank value of the sixth field and insert it when you find a blank value. Reverse the lines again when you're done.

```
tac file.csv | perl -F, -alne '
  $last = $F[6] if $F[6]; 
  $F[6] ||= $last if $last; 
  print join ",", @F;
' | tac
```

You can use `tail -r` instead of `tac` if you're on BSD-derivative.

Comment: Thanks Ill give this a shot.

Comment: Holy moly, this worked like perfectly. This worked more than I needed and fitted my project. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If we assume the ID is stored in the second column, you can for example say:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} FNR==NR {a[$2]=$NF; next} NF<7{$(NF+1)=a[$2]}1' file file
0001,324434344,Sterner,Erik B,B.A,1987,Columbia University
0002,324434344,Sterner,Erik B,M.A,2001,Columbia University
```

This reads the file twice: once to store data and then to print it.

On the first iteration it populates an array `data[2nd field] = last field`. Then, on the second iteration it adds that field if the row contains less than 7 columns.

Comment: You don't have to copy the  `$`, it is just my prompt that I copy to then show the output.

Comment: Ah, rookie mistake, missed that lol. Thanks worked like a charm! I appreciate it.